# Passing Mysql functions through Zend Framework Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

How can I set `current_timestamp` in Mysql database using Zend Framework?

I do this for an update query:

```
$data=array("usercode"=>$username,
                "active"=>1,
                "activation_tme"=>"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");
```

The problem is that Zend framework changes `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` to `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'` and Mysql get it as a string and the result is `000000000000` in time column.

Answer (score 3):

Use :

```
$data = array("usercode"       => $username,
              "active"         => 1,
              "activation_tme" => new Zend_Db_Expr('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'));
```

Documentation: [Zend_Db_Table Programmer's Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html)